# How do I create a temp file and write to it then allow users to download it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on my first application and I need some help with allowing my users to download a text file with certain variables that are being displayed on the page.

Take a shopping list for example.
Let's say you allow your users to create a shopping list of products, and then display the shopping list with the items on a shopping list page,

 **e.g. localhost:3000/list/my-list**

Take a look at the example code below (which is probably incorrect):

```
File.open('shopping_list.txt', 'w') do |file|
  file.puts 'Item 1: #{product_1.name}'
  file.puts 'Item 2: #{product_2.name}'
  file.puts 'Item 3: #{product_3.name}'
end
```

Which then creates a text file that has the following content:

```
Item 1: Eggs
Item 2: Butter
Item 3: Bread
```

Users should then be able to download this file (i don't want this file to be stored on the server) via a download link.

I have no idea how to achieve this, but I'm hoping you guys can guide me. :D

**TL;DR**

- create text files populated with model data (perhaps create a method to achieve this?)
- text files should not be stored on the server, but created as users click the download button (not sure if this is the rails way but perhaps someone could show me a better way)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am assuming there is a resource for `List` with the attribute `name` as the name of the list and a list `has_many` Item which has an attribute `description`

First off, create a download path change your routes `config/routes.rb`

```
resources :lists do
  member {get "download"}
end
```

Now if you run a `rake routes` in the console you should see a route like

```
/lists/:id/download
```

Whats more you should now have the helpers `download_list_url` & `download_list_path` to use in your view like

```
<ul>
<% @lists.each do |list| %>
  <li> <%= list.name %> - <%= link_to 'Download List', download_list_path(list) %> </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

In your `lists_controller` add the action, and as you dont actually want to keep the file on the server disk just stream the data as a string

```
def download
  list = List.find(params[:id])
  send_data list.as_file,
    :filename => "#{list.name}.txt",
    :type => "text/plain"
end
```

Finally you see I have used a `as_file` method which you should add to the model (I prefer not to do this stuff in controllers, fat models, skinny controllers). So in the `List` model

```
def as_file
  output = [self.name]
  self.items.each {|item| output << item.description }
  output.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: Could you help me out with a quick issue I have modifying your code? I want to create something like this gist, but have no idea how to achieve this: https://gist.github.com/1573917 -- basically i need to be able to enter a different value per line but I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Hope https://gist.github.com/1582262 helps, im not entirely sure of teh associations (if any?) looking at your gist.

Answer (score 3):

You say you don't want to store the file on the server, but "download" it on request; this sounds like you just want to generate and deliver a text document in response to the download link.  There are several approaches, but you want to be sure of setting the mime-type so the browser sees it as a text file instead of an html document.

```rb
product_info = [
    "Item 1: #{product_1.name}",
    "Item 2: #{product_2.name}",
    "Item 3: #{product_3.name}",
  ].join("\n")

render :text => product_info # implies :content_type => Mime::Type["text/plain"]
```

BTW, your example with open/puts above won't output what you think since single-quoted strings don't interpolate.

Comment: Oh, I thought they would interpolate like they do in ruby. I was reading this ruby book and tried it out and it seemed to work fine. It created the files with the quotes etc.

Comment: try this in irb: `foo = 'bar'; puts '+#{foo}+', "+#{foo}+"`; you'll get "+#{foo}+\n+bar+" printed. The first line didn't interpolate foo because the string is single-quoted.

Comment: None of these comments can help me make progress towards reaching my goal though :(  Do you know where I could find some help to solve the problem in the example? Like, the entire code of the example. I'm surprised railscasts.com hasn't created something about file creation.

Answer (score 3):

so, you wish to :

- `create text files populated with model data (perhaps create a method
  to achieve this?)`
- `text files should not be stored on the server, but
  created as users click the download button (not sure if this is the
  rails way but perhaps someone could show me a better way)`

You have the right idea, here's what to do :

1. Create a method in your model to generate the text file contents. Let's say this method is called `list_data`
2. It seems like you have an existing controller action called `my_list`. Hence we can call our new method in the controller like so :

.

```
def my_list
  # pre-existing code
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html   # show html page as before
    format.text do
      send_data @list.list_data, :content_type => 'text/plain', :filename => 'my-shopping-list.txt'
    end
  end
end
```

To link to the download, just use `link_to :action => my_list, :format => 'text'`

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data for full docs on `send_data`

Caveat & explanations : Using the method above, there isn't really an explicit creation of files, Rails is streaming it for you. Hence this method is not suitable for very large files, or when the generation of the file content will take a while. Use a delayed method to generate the file and store it - the file contents somewhere if that's the case - but we can use send_data once it has been generated

Comment: The file sizes will be very small, as it's not going to be an actual shopping list.

Comment: Where do I need to place the `my_list` method though? Controller, model or helper? I've tried all 3 but get errors.

Comment: @imjp in the controller :) I see you have already solved it. Good luck in your rails journey

Answer (score 1):

You could try a combination of TempFile and send_file. In your controller action ..

```
file = Tempfile.new('foo')
file.write("hello world")
file.close

send_file file.path
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. How would link to this generated file in my view though? Also, could I just pass the ruby code in a method to dynamically create files for my users?

Comment: <a href="/link/to/my/download_action?someparam=2">Download</a>

Answer (score 0):

At Rails 2.3 you can use [Template Streaming](https://github.com/oggy/template_streaming). Working with Redmine I can remember something like that, you have to adapt for your case. Reference: [Streaming and file downloads](http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6380-action-controller-streaming-and-file-downloads)

```
require "prawn" 
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

  # Generate a PDF document with information on the client and return it.
  # The user will get the PDF as a file download.
  def download_pdf
    client = Client.find(params[:id])
    send_data(generate_pdf, :filename => "#{client.name}.pdf", :type => "application/pdf")
  end

private

  def generate_pdf(client)
    Prawn::Document.new do
      text client.name, :align => :center
      text "Address: #{client.address}" 
      text "Email: #{client.email}" 
    end.render
  end

end
```

Using the Thong Kuah you must just change the "content_type" param:

```
def my_list
  # pre-existing code
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html   # show html page as before
    format.text do
      send_data @list.list_data, :content_type => 'text/plain', :filename => 'my-shopping-list.txt'
    end
  end
end
```